# Adding Dynamic Bootstrap HTML Elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

1. Having problems CSS alignments with dynamically added HTML elements.
2. How am i able to get newly added elements' id ?

JS file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add").click(function (e) {
        $("#items").append('
                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="text" name="input[]" placeholder="something something" class="form-control input-sm text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default delete">
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
            </button>
                    </div>
                </div>');
    });
    $("body").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
        $(this).parent("div").parent("div").remove();
    });
});
```

HTML File

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <div id="items">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" name="input[]" placeholder="something Else here" class="form-control input-sm text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="btn btn-success" id="add">Add new fields</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My page's appearance after pressing Add Field button 2 times

> [image: My page's appearance after pressing Add Field button 2 times]

Comment: Are you really using the script as you pasted it here? You can't use the html string like that. It will throw errors.

Comment: Yes i am, and not having errors, where should i edit ?

Comment: You should have it inline and not use new lines or use string concatenation

Comment: Could you post more HTML structure and CSS? It's hard to reproduce and understand the problem. I only noticed a small thing and left a comment in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qttjomhq/1/). You can use that fiddle to put your complete example

Comment: Here Your code on Bootply http://www.bootply.com/k1l6hH6qSz

Comment: Thank you Spookey and Danko. I'll try both. But @Danko as you can see the new generated fields are left-aligned and i would like to align each field in a row. I did that too but it is still left aligned and not aligned in the same column with the previous ones.

Comment: Do you mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qttjomhq/3/) (updated link to fix script delete action)? As I mentioned in the fiddle comment, your HTML string has an extra parent div that seems to mess up the format. I removed the class of the div

Comment: Check this http://www.bootply.com/QvCxm9dOdB don't add an entire row element